# How to implement Multiple TikTok Pixels on Website

Tags: web, tiktok

Currently I have integrated tiktok pixel on my website with

```
<script>
    !function (w, d, t) {
        w.TiktokAnalyticsObject=t;var ttq=w[t]=w[t]||[];ttq.methods=["page","track","identify","instances","debug","on","off","once","ready","alias","group","enableCookie","disableCookie"],ttq.setAndDefer=function(t,e){t[e]=function(){t.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}};for(var i=0;i<ttq.methods.length;i++)ttq.setAndDefer(ttq,ttq.methods[i]);ttq.instance=function(t){for(var e=ttq._i[t]||[],n=0;n<ttq.methods.length;n++
        )ttq.setAndDefer(e,ttq.methods[n]);return e},ttq.load=function(e,n){var i="https://analytics.tiktok.com/i18n/pixel/events.js";ttq._i=ttq._i||{},ttq._i[e]=[],ttq._i[e]._u=i,ttq._t=ttq._t||{},ttq._t[e]=+new Date,ttq._o=ttq._o||{},ttq._o[e]=n||{};n=document.createElement("script");n.type="text/javascript",n.async=!0,n.src=i+"?sdkid="+e+"&lib="+t;e=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];e.parentNode.insertBefore(n,e)};

        ttq.load('MY_PIXEL_ID');
        ttq.page();
    }(window, document, 'ttq');
</script>
```

And fired some events, example:

```
ttq.track('AddToCart',{
    content_id: productId,
    quantity: 1,
    price: productPrice,
    value: productPrice,
    currency: 'PKR'
});
```

Now I need to implement another pixel ID on same website.

How can I implement both pixels at same time?

I have tried with single pixel ID, I need to implement multiple tiktok pixels at same time

Answer (score 1):

After some searches, I have found the solution

In order to implement multiple pixels on my website

You can follow the sample code below for an example of 3 pixel base codes. Remember to replace the placeholders with your pixel ID before using the sample code.

```
<script>
!function (w, d, t) {
  w.TiktokAnalyticsObject=t;var ttq=w[t]=w[t]||[];ttq.methods=["page","track","identify","instances","debug","on","off","once","ready","alias","group","enableCookie","disableCookie"],ttq.setAndDefer=function(t,e){t[e]=function(){t.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}};for(var i=0;i<ttq.methods.length;i++)ttq.setAndDefer(ttq,ttq.methods[i]);ttq.instance=function(t){for(var e=ttq._i[t]||[],n=0;n<ttq.methods.length;n++)ttq.setAndDefer(e,ttq.methods[n]);return e},ttq.load=function(e,n){var i="https://analytics.tiktok.com/i18n/pixel/events.js";ttq._i=ttq._i||{},ttq._i[e]=[],ttq._i[e]._u=i,ttq._t=ttq._t||{},ttq._t[e]=+new Date,ttq._o=ttq._o||{},ttq._o[e]=n||{};var o=document.createElement("script");o.type="text/javascript",o.async=!0,o.src=i+"?sdkid="+e+"&lib="+t;var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(o,a)};
}(window, document, 'ttq');

ttq.load('BRU69P41M9ALI4R4B2QG');
ttq.page();
</script>

<script>
!function (w, d, t) {
  w.TiktokAnalyticsObject=t;var ttq=w[t]=w[t]||[];ttq.methods=["page","track","identify","instances","debug","on","off","once","ready","alias","group","enableCookie","disableCookie"],ttq.setAndDefer=function(t,e){t[e]=function(){t.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}};for(var i=0;i<ttq.methods.length;i++)ttq.setAndDefer(ttq,ttq.methods[i]);ttq.instance=function(t){for(var e=ttq._i[t]||[],n=0;n<ttq.methods.length;n++)ttq.setAndDefer(e,ttq.methods[n]);return e},ttq.load=function(e,n){var i="https://analytics.tiktok.com/i18n/pixel/events.js";ttq._i=ttq._i||{},ttq._i[e]=[],ttq._i[e]._u=i,ttq._t=ttq._t||{},ttq._t[e]=+new Date,ttq._o=ttq._o||{},ttq._o[e]=n||{};var o=document.createElement("script");o.type="text/javascript",o.async=!0,o.src=i+"?sdkid="+e+"&lib="+t;var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(o,a)};
}(window, document, 'ttq');

ttq.load('pixel_id_2');
ttq.page();
</script>

<script>
!function (w, d, t) {
  w.TiktokAnalyticsObject=t;var ttq=w[t]=w[t]||[];ttq.methods=["page","track","identify","instances","debug","on","off","once","ready","alias","group","enableCookie","disableCookie"],ttq.setAndDefer=function(t,e){t[e]=function(){t.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}};for(var i=0;i<ttq.methods.length;i++)ttq.setAndDefer(ttq,ttq.methods[i]);ttq.instance=function(t){for(var e=ttq._i[t]||[],n=0;n<ttq.methods.length;n++)ttq.setAndDefer(e,ttq.methods[n]);return e},ttq.load=function(e,n){var i="https://analytics.tiktok.com/i18n/pixel/events.js";ttq._i=ttq._i||{},ttq._i[e]=[],ttq._i[e]._u=i,ttq._t=ttq._t||{},ttq._t[e]=+new Date,ttq._o=ttq._o||{},ttq._o[e]=n||{};var o=document.createElement("script");o.type="text/javascript",o.async=!0,o.src=i+"?sdkid="+e+"&lib="+t;var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(o,a)};
}(window, document, 'ttq');

ttq.load('pixel_id_3');
ttq.page();
</script>
```

In this situation, `ttq.track('CompletePayment')` is same as the following lines:

```
ttq.instance('pixel_id_1').track('CompletePayment')
ttq.instance('pixel_id_2').track('CompetePayment')
ttq.instance('pixel_id_3').track('CompletePayment')
```

Because `ttq.track()` will report all the installed Pixels' events.

Reference: https://ads.tiktok.com/gateway/docs/index?identify_key=2b9b4278e47b275f36e7c39a4af4ba067d088e031d5f5fe45d381559ac89ba48&language=ENGLISH&doc_id=1701890973258754#item-link-FAQs